# .htaccess conflicting with same rule

Tags: .htaccess

My rules are below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ doctor_viewprofile.php?hid2=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ blog_mgt_full.php?a=$1&cuserid=$2&cusertype=$3 [L,NC]
```

The second rule is conflicted to first rule and redirected to first rule or page.
I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure why this is happening.

This is happening because both rules **match against the exact same pattern**. Both match against `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$`, so the second rule will never get applied because the first one always matches. There is no way around this because there is no way to tell the difference between what should be a `doctor_viewprofile.php` and what should be a `blog_mgt_full.php`. You can try adding a prefix so that your URLs look like

```
http://www.domain.com/doctor/foo
```

and

```
http://www.domain.com/blog/foo
```

So the rules can be changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^doctor/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ doctor_viewprofile.php?hid2=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ blog_mgt_full.php?a=$1&cuserid=$2&cusertype=$3 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Link for your answer. I know by this way it is possible. But I want the way as described with no /blog or /doctor. Is there any solutions?

Comment: @user1803240 unless there's a way to tell the 2 apart, then no, there is no other solutions.

Comment: Thanks Jon Link for your answer. Is there any way to tell 2 apart?